# Horizontal line after every table

Tags: tables, floats

I want to draw a horizontl line after every table. I tried using `\hrulefill` after every table, but this breaks because of the floating behavior of the tables, e.g. if i have a Code

pseudo MWE:

```
<table>
\hrule
<table>
\hrule
<table>
\hrule
```

the Output will look somewhat like that:

- table
- horizontal line
- table
- horizontal line
- horizontal line
- table

and of course this is not want I want.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\cTable}
{
\begin{table}
  \caption{abc}
  \begin{tabular}{l | l}
    a & a   \\
    b & b   \\
    c & c
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
}

\begin{document}
\cTable
\hrule
\cTable
\hrule
\cTable
\hrule
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, table environments float so you need to draw the line before you close the table environment. The following seems to do what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newenvironment{Table}{\table}{\newline\hrule width\textwidth\endtable}

\newcommand{\cTable}
{
\begin{Table}
  \caption{abc}
  \begin{tabular}{l | l}
    a & a   \\
    b & b   \\
    c & c
  \end{tabular}
\end{Table}
}

\begin{document}
\cTable

\cTable

\cTable

\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]